# Induced maps between spectra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism. If $f^{-1}$ induces a bijection between the ideals of $B$ and a set $U$ of ideals of $A$, and this bijection reflects the inclusion (and reflects the property of being prime), can I conclude that $\operatorname {Spec}f$ is an homeomorphism between $\operatorname {Spec} B$ and $U\cap\operatorname {Spec} A$?

From the hypothesis is immediate that $\operatorname {Spec} f$ induces a (continuous) bijection between $\operatorname {Spec} B$ and $U\cap\operatorname {Spec} A$; to prove that is closed in the image one can use that, for an ideal $I\subseteq B$ and a closed $V(I)$, $$\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}f (V(I))\iff f(\mathfrak p)\subseteq I, \mathfrak p\in U \iff \mathfrak p \subseteq f^{-1} (I),\mathfrak p\in U\iff \mathfrak p \in V(f^{-1}(I))\cap U.$$ Is my arguement correct? If yes, are there notable examples of homomorphisms $f$ with the mentioned properties, other than the projection $A\to A/I$ and the canonical homomorphism $A\to S^{-1} A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One correct claim that can be proven is that if $f:A\to B$ is a homomorphism of rings so that $f^{-1}$ reflects containment of ideals (ie $f^{-1}(I)\subset f^{-1}(J)$ implies $I\subset J$), then the induced map on spectra $\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec B\to\Spec A$ is a homeomorphism on to its image. Here's how:

1. The map $\varphi:\Spec B\to \Spec A$ is continuous: the preimage of some $V(I)$ for $I\subset A$ is $V(f(I)B)$, so the preimage of a closed set is closed (this is general for any map of rings).
2. The map $\varphi$ is injective: if $\mathfrak{q}_1,\mathfrak{q}_2\subset B$ are prime ideals with $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}_1)=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}_2)=\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $A$, then since $f^{-1}$ reflects containment we see that $\mathfrak{q}_1=\mathfrak{q}_2$. Therefore $\varphi$ is a bijection on to its image.
3. The map $\varphi:\Spec B\to \varphi(\Spec B)$ is closed. Suppose $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ is in the image of $\varphi$, that is, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ with $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$. Further, suppose that $\mathfrak{p}$ is in the closure of $\varphi(V(I))$ for some ideal $I\subset B$. As $\overline{\varphi(V(I))}=V(f^{-1}(I))$ for any map of rings (where the closure is taken in $\Spec A$), we see that $f^{-1}(I)\subset f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$, and as $f^{-1}$ reflects containment we must have $I\subset\mathfrak{q}$. Therefore $\mathfrak{q}\in V(I)$ and $\varphi(V(I))$ is closed in $U$. (This looks to be approximately what you've written, but I don't find your presentation to be so clear - maybe that's my fault.)
4. A continuous closed bijection is a homeomorphism, so $\varphi:\Spec B\to \varphi(\Spec B)$ is a homeomorphism.

Note that if we drop this assumption about reflecting containment, we get counterexamples: if $R$ is a discrete valuation ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then the map $f:R\to R/\mathfrak{m}\times \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ is a continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism and $f^{-1}$ does not reflect containment. (This is noted in the other answer and its comments.)

As far as a characterization of what sort of maps of rings have this property other than (compositions of) localizations and quotients, I'm not sure that there is a well-known description. Any such map will be an epimorphism of rings, and there's a [seminar](http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_/) by Samuel about these that I'm aware of but have not dug in to much. Some of the examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) should satisfy your assumptions and also give you an idea that this is maybe not such a simple condition to classify.

Comment: By $\varphi:\text{Spec}(B)\longrightarrow \varphi(\text{Spec}(B))$ being a closed map, you mean that $\varphi$ maps a closed subset of $\text{Spec}(B)$ to a set that is closed in $\text{Spec}(A)$ or in $\varphi(\text{Spec}(B))$ endowed with the subspace topology? (From the proof, it seems to me that you mean the later, but perhaps they mean the same?)

Comment: I ask about this because I want to prove that $\varphi:\text{Spec}(B)\longrightarrow V(\ker(f))$ is a homeomorphism when $f$ is surjective. When the ring homomorphism $f$ is surjective, it surely reflects the containment of ideals.  So, we are under the same setup. And, what I need to show is just that $\varphi(\text{Spec}(B))=V(\ker(f))$. But I can only show is that $$\overline{\varphi(\text{Spec}(B))}=V(\ker(f)),$$ where the closure is taken in $\text{Spec}(A)$.

Comment: If $\varphi:\text{Spec}(B)\longrightarrow\varphi(\text{Spec}(B))$ being closed means the former, I can conclude that $\varphi(\text{Spec}(B))$ is closed in $\text{Spec}(A)$, and thus the closure in the last comment is the image itself. If it means the later, I don't really know what to do then...

Comment: I mean the map $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \varphi(\operatorname{Spec} B)$ is closed, where the latter is endowed with the subspace topology. The other option you list is wrong in general: think about a localization like $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[1/2]$, for instance. If you're looking to show that $f$ surjective implies $\operatorname{Spec} f$ a closed immersion, that's covered in a ton of other questions on this site and other textbooks. (You may also slightly alter the proof in the answer to show $\varphi(\operatorname{Spec} B)$ is closed.)

Comment: Great answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

No, continuous bijections are not homeomorphisms, even if they come from ring homomorphisms. For example, if $A$ is an integral domain with two prime ideals $0$ and $\mathfrak p$, $K$ is its field of fractions and $k = A/\mathfrak p$ then the ring homomorphism $f : A \to K \times k$ given by $f(x) = (x+\mathfrak p , x)$ gives a continuous bijection but not a homeomorphism.

This is because $\text{Spec } A $ and $\text{Spec } K \times k $ are both spaces of two points (you can clearly see that $f^{-1}$ is surjective between them, so it is bijective), but $\text{Spec } A $ has the topology given by $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0, \mathfrak p\}\}$ while $\text{Spec } K \times k $ has the discrete topology

Comment: I agree that this is a counterexample to the statement that continuous bijections are not homeomorphisms, but I don't think this addresses the question that the OP posed. In particular, this map does not satisfy the requirement that $f^{-1}$ reflects inclusion: the preimage of the ideal $0\times k$ is $(0)$ and the preimage of $K\times0$ is $\mathfrak{p}$, so $(0)\subset\mathfrak{p}$ but $0\times k\not\subset K\times 0$.